# Transitivity of induced representation of tensor product?

Tags: representation-theory, tensor-products

By the transitivity of induced representation, we have $Ind_K^G(V)\simeq Ind_H^G(Ind_K^H(V))$. Similarly, let $H_1\subset G_1$ and $H_2\subset G_2$, does we have  $Ind_{G_1\times G_2}^{G}\left(Ind_{H_1}^{G_1}V_1 \otimes Ind_{H_2}^{G_2}V_2\right)\simeq Ind_{H_1\times H_2}^{G}V_1\otimes V_2$? I don't find some references about this.

Comment: Yes, you just need to check that $\text{Ind}_{H_1}^{G_1} V_1 \otimes \text{Ind}_{H_2}^{G_2} V_2 \cong \text{Ind}_{H_1 \times H_2}^{G_1 \times G_2} (V_1 \otimes V_2)$ then use transitivity.

Comment: Yeah, this solved my problem.